# How do I remove this entry from the shell context menu?

Tags: shell, context-menu

[image]

This entry ONLY appears if and when I select an icon on the desktop otherwise it's not there.

I tried [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-useless-items-from-right-click-context-menu-by-hacking-registry/) but it doesn't appear in the registry entry there.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ShellExView by NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).  It can be used to enable/disable shell extensions including context menu items.

Comment: I don't want to enable/disable, I want it permanently removed.

Comment: Disabling it will remove it from the menu,  You can also have the program show the clsid in the registry.  You can back that up and then delete it.  Since a shell extension can do more then one thing, if it removes something you want: restore from backup.  And just disable that menu entry.  If not it is gone for good.

Comment: No, you don't get it. I don't want it simply disabled and stay there in the registry. I want it removed permanently from my computer, this includes removing it from registry.